# createContext using a dynamic object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

### 1. Static object

To create context based on a static object, I use this code:

```js
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

const user = {uid: '27384nfaskjnb2i4uf'};

const UserContext = createContext(user);

export default UserContext;
```

This code works fine.

### 2. Dynamic object

But if I need to create context after fetching data, I use this code:

```js
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = () => {

    // Let's suppose I fetched data and got user object
    const user = {uid: '18937829FJnfmJjoE'};

    // Creating context
    const context = createContext(user);

    // Returning context
    return context;

}

export default UserContext;
```

### Problem

When I debugg option 1, `console.log(user)` returns the object. Instead, option 2, `console.log(user)` returns `undefined`. What I'm missing?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext }     from 'react';
import UserContext                                    from './UserContext';

const ProjectSelector = (props) => {

    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    console.log(user);

    return(...);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: "This is not working." Can you tell us why?

Comment: The second UserContext is a function, the first is not. Maybe make the second one const UserContext = { ...

Comment: I modified the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one thing i would suggest is move this logic to a react component itself.
anhow you need to use a Provider in which you will set value to be the value consumers need to consume.useEffect is greatway to do asynchronous updates, like your requirment.
so , use a state variable as value of provider.in useEffect you fetch the data and update the state variable which in turn will update context value.
following is the code

**UserContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

export default UserContext;
```

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("here");
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        setUser(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        <DummyConsumer />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**DummyConsumer.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from "./UserContext";

const DummyConsumer = () => {
  const dataFromContext = useContext(UserContext);
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(dataFromContext)}</div>;
};

export default DummyConsumer;
```

demo:[anychronus context value providing](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-greider-c2gpn)